# How do I add id attirbute to find() function in BeatifulSoup?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape from a weather website, and this is what I have so far:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
query = input("What city: ")
url = f'https://www.bing.com/search?pglt=169&q=weather+{query}'
headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/114.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/114.0.1823.82'}
r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
s = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')
weather = s.find('div', class_="wtr_currTemp b_focusTextLarge")
timescale = s.find('div', {id: 'wtr_svg_cntr'})
print(timescale)
```

However, I don't think I'm doing the id right in the timescale variable. The HTML code goes as follows:

```
<div id="wtr_svg_cntr" aria-label="Hourly forecast (Thu 20) 6 PM: 88°, Precipitation: 3%; 9 PM: 77°, Precipitation: 9%; 12 AM: 73°, Precipitation: 23%; 3 AM: 70°, Precipitation: 4%; 6 AM: 66°, Precipitation: 1%; 9 AM: 70°; 12 PM: 76°; 3 PM: 78°, Precipitation: 1%" role="img">
```

How do I write the id part into my find method?

I tried to do it as I just showed, but it's returning None, meaning that it can't find that id, but it's there, so I think I'm just writing it wrong. Help please? Greatly appreciated!

Comment: Changing `id` to `"id"` made it return something for me. I don't know if it's the correct though. It's just this: `<div aria-label="Hourly forecast" id="wtr_svg_cntr" role="img"></div>` perhaps missing something (although it could depend on the city??)

Comment: @juanpethes Yes, that is correct: `id` is a built-in function. `{ id: '...' }` creates a dictionary with a function as the key whereas that of `{ 'id': '' }` is a string. That said, I'm voting to close this question as typo.

Comment: The id is the same for all places, last time I checked

Answer (score 1):

```
id
```

is a default python function

```
"id"
```

is a string, and is the name of the attribute you want to find.

Simply replace `timescale = s.find('div', {id: 'wtr_svg_cntr'})` with `timescale = s.find('div', {"id": 'wtr_svg_cntr'})`, and you should be good to go :-).

Comment: @Daniel No problem :). Don't hesitate to mark this answer as correct ;)